# Регулярное выражение - убрать цифры, но не совсем

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регулярным выражением.
Имеется строка вида:

`Кабель 2 кабель1 12345 кабель12-a 12-a`

Что должно быть в итоге:

`Кабель кабель1 кабель12-а 12-а`

Набросал: `preg_replace('/(\s{1,}?\d)/ui','',$text)`

Выдает: `Кабель кабель1 кабель12-а2-а`

Не хватает знаний и логики, как обрабатывать, например -> `12-а`

Comment: может так / \d+ / ? Просто любое число окруженное пробелами

Comment: @Artyom вроде подходит..может кто укажет на подводные камни (кроме остающихся цифр в конце) ) Тем не менее, спасибо )

Comment: @sousage1212 да, еще могут быть оставшиеся цифры в начале. И пробелов между словами может (или не может?) быть много, они останутся. Чтобы это учесть, можно использовать такое выражение: `(^| )[\d ]+(?= |$)`. Или такое: `(^| )[\d ]+($| )`, но заменять тогда надо на пробел, а не пустую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```php
preg_replace('/\s*(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)/', '', $text)
```

Таким образом можно удалить все числа между пробельными символами или началом/концом строки вместе с пробелами в начале.

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/2Ysdxh/1).